# What is a "monster" in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, word-request

English "monster" comes from Latin *monstrum* "divine omen, supernatural occurrence", from *moneō* "warn". Later this shifted to the meaning it has in English, a horrifying or evil creature.

But before this shift happened, how would I talk about "monsters" in general? A word specifically for supernatural horrors, or specifically for natural ones, would be fine.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but this could help someone else find it: I once heard Roman law considered the case when a woman gave birth something different than a human being. If I remember right, the word used in Spanish was _monstruo_ (monster), so the answer _could_ be in Roman law.

Comment: Did the meaning shift?  I always thought that anything horrifying and monstrous was called a _monstrum_ precisely because it was interpreted as a "supernatural occurrence", intended as a warning by the divine powers.  That is to say, _monstrum_ did always mean "monster" in the sense we currently understand it (horrifying) although we don't now necessarily associate something malformed as a divine omen (but we do associate monsters in horror films as "evil" to some extent).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For natural monsters, perhaps ***belua***:

> ***Belua*** immanis, crocodillus ille qui in Nilo gignitur …
>
> That colossal monster, the crocodile born in the Nile …

Apuleius, *Apologia*, 8

*Belua* is often used for sea-monster (*belua ponti*) and it's sometimes ambiguous whether this means something like a whale (a natural 'monster') or something more supernatural.  See for example: Ovid, *Metamorphoses*, 5.18; Lucan, *Civil War*, 8.764

Here, Lucretius speaks of the fanciful shapes clouds sometimes appear to take:

> *inde alios trahere atque inducere **belua** nimbos*
>
> after them some monster pulling and dragging other clouds

Lucretius, *De Rerum Natura*, 4.140 (trans. W. H. D. Rouse)

This, then, is a cross between natural and supernatural! Vergil uses it to describe a supernatural monster - *belua Lernae* - when Aeneas is in the underworld confronting all sorts of ghouls and horrors (*Aeneid*, 6.287).

Another option is ***portentum*** (from [*portendo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=portentum&la=la#lexicon)).  This obviously has semantic overlap with *monstrum*.

> *diram qui contudit hydram*
>   *notaque fatali **portenta** labore subegit,*
>   *comperit invidiam supremo fine domari*
>
> He [Hercules] who crushed the Hydra and laid low with fated toil the
>   monsters of story found that Envy is quelled only by death that comes
>   at last.

Horace, *Epistles*, 2.1.10-12 (trans.H. R. Fairclough)

This passage is clearly referencing supernatural monsters.  It is interesting that Cicero uses both *belua* and *portenta* in the following.  Perhaps he is differentiating here between both natural and supernatural monsters:

> *quae plurimorum saeculorum et eventorum memoriam litteris continet,*
>   *bovem quendam putari deum, quem Apim Aegyptii nominant, multaque alia*
>   ***portenta*** apud eosdem et cuiusque generis **beluas** numero consecratas
>   *deorum*
>
> [in Egypt] ... which preserves written records of the events of countless ages, a
>   bull, which the Egyptians call Apis, is deemed a god, and many other
>   monsters and animals of every sort are held sacred as divine

Cicero, *De Re Publica*, 3.9 (trans. Clinton W. Keyes)

Lastly, Apuleius here lists many types of scary creatures, but I think [***occursacula***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=occursacula&la=la#lexicon), [***terriculamenta***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=terriculamenta&la=la#lexicon), and ***formidamina*** (from [*formido*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=formido&la=la#lexicon))  are all good generic terms for monsters in general:

> *At tibi, Aemiliane, pro isto mendacio duit deus iste superum et inferum commeator utrorumque deorum malam gratiam, semperque obvias
>   species mortuorum, quidquid umbrarum est usquam, quidquid lemurum,
>   quidquid manium, quidquid larvarum, oculis tuis oggerat, omnia noctium
>   **occursacula**, omnia bustorum **formidamina**, omnia sepulchrorum **terriculamenta**, a quibus tamen aevo et merito haud longe abes.*
>
> But as for you, Aemilianus, may that god, the intermediary between the
>   upper and lower worlds, repay you for that lie with the ill will of
>   the gods above and below; may he ever bring dead men’s forms to meet
>   your eyes, every shade, phantom, spectre, ghost that ever was, every
>   **apparition of the night**, every **horror** of the pyre, every **terror** of the
>   graveyard, to all of which your age and just deserts have brought you
>   near.

Apuleius, *Apologia*, 64 (trans. Christopher P. Jones)